# how to replace a context.Request.Url.Query content?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, proxy

I want to find if the url query contains '10.123.97.202' particular string should replace string with new values '10.167.81.136'. But I am facing issue in replacing the content .
Can you anyone suggest the solution?

```
HttpContext context;
if (context.Request.Url.Query Contains("10.123.97.202"))
{
    context.Request.Url.Query  = context.Request.Url.Query.Replace("10.123.97.202", "10.167.81.136")
}
```

Comment: What is the issue? Implementing the Replace() method?

Comment: yes , Want to replace the URL with New value

Comment: As far as I know, the whole context.Request object is read-only, and the Query property of context.Request.Url is definitely read-only. You can see here that it only has a `get` accessor, not a `set`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.query(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: is there any solution ?. i want toi replace the 'string '

Comment: What is the goal of this? Perhaps if we had more information then we could suggest another solution

Comment: I have one URL which has IP address , Which needs to be replaced with new server,